# Understanding Android Room migrations, first and following runs of app

Tags: android, android-room

I'd like to have the following migrations (development cycle):

- Migrate schema - v.1
- Migrate data (seed) - v.2
- Migrate schema - v.3
- Migrate data (seed) - v.4

In Android Room examples github repo I saw that migrations can be used to migrate data as well as schema and I want to use it.

I get desired behavior for the following steps:

- I have no migrations and I run the app first time
- Db and schema are being created with v.1
- I update code with 1->2, 2->3, 3->4 migrations and build & run the app again
- Both db schema and data are being updated properly, as I would expect

But if after that I do fresh install (remove db) - I see that no migrations are being executed, only schema is auto-created using @Entity classes of the project. Thus I don't have control over data migration.

I'd like every fresh install to run all migrations starting from 1->2, is it possible? Or is there some Room practice I'm not aware of to achieve the development cycle above?

Comment: Room db migration happens only when there is the difference in db version i.e user has already app with db and then user updated the app, if there is any change is db version then room will migrate db according to migration code provided. IF user fresh install app then there will be no room migration.

Comment: @AmitTiwary I'm just wondering how in this case Android developers migrate data? I know that there's 'on create' hook and one can use it to populate db with initial data, but I find 'data' migrations more convenient, maybe because i'm from backend side :)